# Create insert statement from three variables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm generating a list from a nested array containing tablename, fieldname and fieldvalue, with repeating tablenames, i.e.

```
Table1, Field1, Value1
Table1, Field2, Value2
Table1, Field3, Value3
Table2, Field1, Value1
Table3, Field1, Value1
Table3, Field2, Value2
...
```

where the number of tables and fields vary from array to array, I want to write an INSERT to persist the values in a mysql table.  To generate the sql I'm using:

```
function array2sql($tableName,$key,$element){
            if ($element){
            $sql="INSERT into $tableName ($key) values ($element);";
            }
}
```

Which is resulting in:

```
INSERT into Table1 (Field1) values (Value1);
INSERT into Table1 (Field2) values (Value2);
... etc.
```

Is there a better way to create the insert statement?

Clarification on the array that is generating the variables:

The array is nested, the array name being used to set the tablename is similar to this:

```
Table1[(Field1=>Value1,Field2=>Value2, Field3=>Value3),
     [Table2(Field1=>Value1),
         [Table3(Field1=>Value1)]
     ]
]
```

The nested arrays are parsed first, discarding any subarrays with [0] as a key.

Comment: values can be `INSERT into Table1 (Field1) values (x),(y),(z)` you dont need on insert each

Comment: Yes there is! Never include data originating from outside directly into SQL. Use prepared statements. Also turn emulation of prepared statements off. At least real_escape strings, if you really need to use dynamic identifiers.

Comment: A single [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) can be used over and over to insert data. That's the most straight-forward way to do this.

Comment: @Quasimodo - understood, but I'm trying to get it to function first, then I can lock it down.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or in an array like this

```
$tab = array(
    array('table1','champ1','valeur1'),
    array('table1','champ2','valeur2'),
    array('table2','champ1','valeur1'),
    array('table2','champ2','valeur2'),
    array('table2','champ3','valeur3')
    );
```

then :

```
function array2sql($tab){
    $sql = '';
    $fields = '';
    $values = '';
    $extable = $tab[0][0];
    foreach( $tab as $line ) {
        if ($extable == $line[0]) {
            $fields .= $line[1].',';
            $values .= $line[2].',';
        } else {
            $sql .= 'INSERT INTO ' . $extable . ' (' . rtrim($fields, ',') . ') VALUES (' . rtrim($values, ',') . ');';
            $fields = '';
            $values = '';
            $extable = $line[0];
        }
    }
    $sql .= 'INSERT INTO ' . $extable . ' (' . rtrim($fields, ',') . ') VALUES (' . rtrim($values, ',') . ');';
    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my array is multidimensional.